# bash function for `pv fileName | sha256sum -b`

Tags: bash, alias

I'm on Linux Mint 18.2 with GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

I'd like to re-define `sha256sum` with my function defined in `.bash_aliases` for it to show progress because I use it for 100+GB files often.

The function follows:

```
function sha256sum {

    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
    {
        \sha256sum --help
    }
    else
    {
        pv $1 | \sha256sum -b
    }
    fi

}
```

But there are some culprits, which I can't explain.

For one it behaves unexpectedly, I somehow managed to force it to "eat" the parameter.

Specifically, the following file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.0K Jul 24 12:29 testdisk.log
```

Now it outputs the file's size, never-ending:

```
vlastimil@vb-nb-mint ~ $ sha256sum testdisk.log 
1.92KiB 0:00:00 [40.8MiB/s] [====================================================>] 100%            
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
...
...
...
^C
[1]+  Stopped                 pv $1 | \sha256sum -b
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried different structure, with and without braces, with and without semicolon, and like for an hour no better result than this one.

**EDIT1:**

Removing the `\` sign for the function to look like:

```
function sha256sum {

    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
    {
        sha256sum --help
    }
    else
    {
        pv "$1" | sha256sum -b
    }
    fi

}
```

Results in:

```
1.92KiB 0:00:00 [56.8MiB/s] [====================================================>] 100%            
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
1.92KiB
...
...
...
^C
[2]+  Stopped                 pv "$1" | sha256sum -b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of the occurences of `\sha256sum` in your function's body is a
recursive call to that function. Prefixing the name with a backslash
prevents it from being interpreted as an alias, but does not prevent
interpreting it as a function.

You want to write `command sha256sum` instead of `\sha256sum`; for
example, keeping the layout of your original function:

```
function sha256sum {

    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
    {
        command sha256sum --help
    }
    else
    {
        pv "$1" | command sha256sum -b
    }
    fi

}
```

Comment: Additionally, the curly braces are not needed.

Comment: Yes--there are several things I would do differently if the function was for me to use; I made only the smallest changed needed to, hopefully, answer the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I am aware they aren't necessary.

Comment: @dhag You did good. Thanks. I didn't know of the `command` until now.

Answer (score 2):

As [dhag points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399123/116858), you are recursively calling your function.

He rightly suggests you drop the backslashes and use `command` instead.

Additionally, the curly braces are not needed (but are allowed).

This is what my function would look like:

```
sha256sum () {
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        pv "$1" | command sha256sum -
    else
        command sha256sum --help
    fi
}
```

A downside of this shell function is that you can't pass command line flags to `sha256sum`, or multiple input files.